# Reading integer data from a file using fortran

Tags: fortran

I am trying to read in a list of integers (length is unknown) from a file and save it as an array. I think I am doing everything correct but the values are not being read into the array. I know there are lot of question like this but I am unable spot the problem with my code. Can someone help me find the mistake I am making in my code/approach?
The list of integers look like this:

```
3
4
90
1267
1668
49
570
1271
```

And this is my code:

---

```
    PROGRAM read_nodes

    implicit none
    integer :: n, ios,i, count_lines
    logical :: existfile=.FALSE.
    integer,dimension(:), allocatable :: hnset_nodes, nodes, tmp
    character(len=80) :: input_line, filename='CooledNodes.txt'
    
    allocate(nodes(5))
    
    INQUIRE(file=filename, exist=existfile)  ! check if file exists
      IF (existfile) then    
        print*, 'File exists'
      ELSE
          write(*,*) 'ERROR: The file "CooledNodes.txt" does not exist'
          stop
      END IF
    
    n = count_lines(filename) ! find number of lines in file
    print*, 'number of lines=', n
    
    if(n>size(nodes)) then
      allocate(tmp(n))
      tmp(1:size(nodes)) = nodes
      call MOVE_ALLOC(tmp, nodes)
    end if 
    print*, 'size of array=', size(nodes)
    
    open(unit=10, file='CooledNodes.txt', status='old', action='read') 
     
    DO i=1,n
       read(10,*, iostat=ios) nodes(i)
       print*, 'reading'
       print*, nodes(i)
       if(ios<0) exit           
    END DO       
    
    allocate(hnset_nodes(n), stat=ios)
    !if(ios==0) then
    !print*, 'array size=', size(hnset_nodes)
    !end if
    hnset_nodes=nodes
    open(unit=15, file='nodes.txt')
    write(15, fmt='(I5)') hnset_nodes   ! writes the values read as a verification step.  
  

    END PROGRAM read_nodes

integer function count_lines(filename) 
    
    implicit none
    
    character(len=80) :: filename
    integer :: ios, nlines=0
    logical :: existfile=.false.

      open(unit=10, file='CooledNodes.txt', status='old', action='read') 
      print*, 'File opened'
       
        DO
            read(10, *, iostat=ios)   ! counting number of lines in the file
            if (ios/=0) exit
            print*, 'reading file'           
            nlines=nlines+1       
        END DO
        count_lines= nlines
        
end function count_lines
```

---

The codes executes without any errors but prints out zeros to the file. It seems like it does not read the values in the file at all.

Comment: What exactly happens? How does the result look like? What exactly is wrong? Does the code print something incorrect or is there an error message?

Comment: You're not closing the file in `count_lines` so it's still open when you open it in the main body. Add `close(10)` at the end of `count_lines` and it looks like everything works.

Comment: Can you make sure you post *exactly* the code you are using. The above fails to compile for me as the return type of the function has not been specified. Also I am amazed it runs without error for the reason @veryreverie gives

Comment: @IanBush yeah, I had to put the function in a contains block and tweak a couple of lines to get the program to see the function.

Comment: Sorry, I had 'integer function count_lines' in the code but I think while adjusting the code block it got deleted. Yes, I forgot to add close(10) and now it works. That was such a basic mistake. Thank you so much!!